# Linux - how to turn off space highlighting

Tags: vi

I am working on a shell script but noticed that space character is unnecessarily highlighting which is very annoying.

[image]

Tried to turn it off by :syntax off but that removes highlighting for all. Please suggest how can I turn off the space highlight.

Comment: We need more information. Is this when you're typing at a shell? Are you in a text editor? If so, which one? Vim/Nano/Emacs? I'm presuming that from `:syntax off` you're in vim, but please specify this in your post.

Comment: this comes when I do "vi"  for shell script.

Comment: If you have questions about using vi, [vi.se] would be the best place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it might be highlighting the last search term. Try running `:nohlsearch` (or `:noh` for short).

If you perform another search, highlighting will be enabled again. To disable search highlighting entirely, run `:set nohlsearch` (or `:set nohls`).

Before I knew about the above commands, I used to search for a string that wouldn't exist in my file, for example `/rhrp`. That would make the highlighting effectively disappear.